# Seaborn line subplot using python data frame for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Below is my data frame. Each Center can have different state

```
Center  Month Start State   Cost          Cost FACTOR
376  1/1/2022   NC  1035.44608  1098.82707
376  2/1/2022   SC  1098.82707  1407.55259
890  3/1/2022   NC  1407.55259  1356.45088
890  4/1/2022   GA  1356.45088  1305.31729
376  5/1/2022   GA  1305.31729  1466.9539
890  9/1/2022   NC  2148.07146  2024.72621
376  10/1/2022  NC  2024.72621  1859.82234
754  11/1/2022  SC  1859.82234  1520.82405
754  12/1/2022  NC  1520.82405  1528.37079
754  1/1/2023   GA  1528.37079  516.421
```

I am trying to use seaborn line subplot to plot cost and cost factor using for loop using enumerate by passing the data frame column(center and state) as parameter. But all the 3 sublots are giving same results.

The below code gives 3 subplots with same graph values.

I am expecting the below

1. 3 line sublots showing 'Cost' and 'Cost Factor' by 'Center'
2. line sublots showing 'Cost' and 'Cost Factor' for every Center & State combination

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns 
center = df_test.CENTER.unique() 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(20, 12)) 
for i, col in enumerate(center):
    xp = df_test['MONTH_START']     
    yp = df_test['COST']     
    Yp = df_test['COST_FACTOR']     
    sns.lineplot(x=xp, y=yp,data=col,ax=ax[i])     
    sns.lineplot(x=xp, y=Yp,data=col,ax=ax[i]) 
    ax[i].legend([f'center {col}'])
```

Comment: 1) `df['Month Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month Start'])` 2) `dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['Center', 'Month Start'], value_vars=['Cost', 'Cost FACTOR'], var_name='Cost Type')` 3) `g = sns.relplot(kind='line', data=dfm, x='Month_Start', y='value', hue='Cost Type', row='Center', height=3, aspect=3)` [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIBlj.png)

Comment: Or 1) `df['Month Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month Start'])` 2) `dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['Center', 'Month Start', 'State'], value_vars=['Cost', 'Cost FACTOR'], var_name='Cost Type')` 3) `g = sns.relplot(kind='line', data=dfm, x='Month Start', y='value', hue='Cost Type', row='Center', col='State', height=3, aspect=3, marker='o')` [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogwJl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to plot 3 plots for each center... To do this, the for loop you have needs to be changed and the data of should be filtered each time so that you get only the specific center. Also, need some adjustments in terms of the legend and title. Updated code below. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns 
center = df_test.CENTER.unique() 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(20, 12)) 

for i in range(len(center)):  ## For each center
    df=df_test[df_test['CENTER'] == center[i]]  ## Get the filtered data
    sns.lineplot(x='MONTH_START', y='COST',data=df,ax=ax[i])  ## Plot cost
    sns.lineplot(x='MONTH_START', y='COST_FACTOR',data=df,ax=ax[i]) ## Plot cost facte
    ax[i].legend(['Cost', 'Cost Factor'])   ## Legend should have the two lines 
    ax[i].title.set_text(f'center {center[i]}')  ## Title for each sub plot
    
plt.tight_layout() ## Finally use this so that the title and axis text dont overlap
```

**Output plot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking. If I want to do a similar subplots by Center and then by State, do I need to have another loop and pass the Center as a parameter ?

Comment: Yes, you can do two FOR loops and filter the data by center and state before plotting. The plots will show up one below the other. If you want them in the form of a grid, you can use something like the example [here](https://dev.to/thalesbruno/subplotting-with-matplotlib-and-seaborn-5ei8)